# Linux network speed is abysmally slow while winXP is ok. Why?

Tags: linux, networking, laptop, wireless-networking

I have a Dell inspiron 640m (1405). I am a reasonably clued in linux user, but I am getting serious networking speed problems.

The networking card is an intel 3945ABG

When wirelessly connecting with windows XP, everything runs fine and the network connection is fast.

When connecting with *any* linux distro, the networking speed is abysmally slow, and the connection drops randomly. (the network is recognised and the connection *is* made however)

Is there any possible reason why that would be?

Help me get the penguin back on my laptop!

**[EDIT]:** Using latest firmware for the card. The module used is iwl3945. unloading/reloading module doesn't change the behaviour. The networking speed is still ridiculously slow. There are no errors in dmesg. Using ArchLinux and module autoloading (tried manual unload/reload too...) .

**[RESOLVED]:** By using ndiswrapper. The iwl3945 driver seemed to be the cause of the problem. Downloading [the windows driver](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R164255&SystemID=XPS_M1210&servicetag=&os=WW1&osl=en&deviceid=9540&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=7&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=1&libid=5&fileid=220545) from dell and using the .INF files works as expected:

- Blacklist iwl3945
- Install the driver:
  `ndiswrapper -i /path/to/***.INF`
- Check that the driver is loaded:
  `ndiswrapper -l`
- Load the ndiswrapper
  module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Ndiswrapper](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ndiswrapper/index.php?title=Main_Page).

Answer (score 4):

Please try these steps:

- Check the output of dmesg and look for error signs::

  ```
  dmesg | grep -i error
  ```
- Try reloading the kernel modules related with your card.

  - Hopefully `lsmod | grep iwl` may show you what you need to unload.
  - I usually need to reload `iwlagn` and `iwlcore`.
  - Use `modprobe -r [module-name]` to remove and `modprobe [module-name]`
  - If you do not have these iwl drivers, you need an update.
- Try `ifconfig wlan0` and see if you have errors.

Comment: Hey Can, No error in dmesg. Tried reloading all modules to no avail. (its iwl3945 for my card) Am using the latest firmware (on Archlinux) which I manually downloaded from XP. Didn't make any difference. Will add info to the main post. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Using ndiswrapper where there is a open source version available...  I I am sharing you pain :)